# How to populate pivot table with fake data in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I use **factory** and **seeder** in laravel to insert fake data in my tables with my models to test its efficiency, now I have a pivot table **post_tag** that has **post_id** and **tag_id**,
how can I insert fake data in the pivot table.Should I make a **model** named **Post_Tag**?
I think this way it's not true...
Thanks

Comment: No it's not the case you will need just a factory for post and an other for tag and then `$faker = Faker::create();
$posts = Post::all();
$tags = Tag::all()->list('id');

foreach ($posts as $post) {
  $post->tag()->attach($faker->randomElement($tags));
}`

Comment: @Maraboc Thank you very much It solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a model called `Post_Tag`. Every model is associated with a `table` from your DB. After creating the model you should create the seed file. 
Of course you could just create the model and insert a new line in your `PostSeeder` file but it's nice to have things organized.